React Typescript: pass interface as a parameter from one functional component to another functional component
I have a react next.js application. where I am trying to pass data using interface props into another component. while running build I am encountering an issue. below are the details.
I have a interface ModelProps
export interface ModelProps  {
modalOpen?: boolean;
data: any;
reloadParent: () => void;
closeModal: () => void;
}

this is my parent component
function page(props: ModelProps) {
    const { modalOpen, data, reloadParent,closeModal } = props;
    return (
        <div>
                <BookingModalPopup modalOpen={modalOpen} data={data} reloadParent={reloadParent} closeModal={closeModal} />
        </div>
    )
}

and this is my child component where I am trying to open a popup modal to show some details
interface RequestData {
   [key: string]: string;
}

function BookingModalPopup(modelProps: ModelProps) {
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]);
const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
const [isMsgModalOpen, setIsMsgModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [isloaderOpen, setIsLoaderOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState<RequestData>({});


return (
    <div>
        <>
        <ModelPopup isOpen={isMsgModalOpen} closeModal={closeMsgModal} msg={msg} />
        <Loader isOpen={isloaderOpen} />
            <My Elements Here>
        </>
    </div>
)
}

export default BookingModalPopup

whenever i am running npm run build it is giving below error
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<ModelProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'modalOpen' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.

any help would be appriciated
TIA

The question here is not complete nor well formatted. Could you please edit this question?

The issue is with the code structure. looks like BookingModalPopup is a component which is being called from page.tsx which also gets called from another component.
remove the page.tsx and directly call BookingModalPopup from another component
for example
function CompA() {

    const [modelOpenT, setModelOpenT] = useState<string>('true');
    const [dataToEdit, setDataToEdit] = useState<any>('false');

   
    return (
        <div>
            <BookingModalPopup parameter1={dataToEdit} parameter2={modelOpenT} /> 
        </div>
    )
}




const BookingModalPopup: React.FC<ModelProps> = ({ parameter1, parameter2 }) => {
   
    return (
        <div>
            <>
            <div className='text-white'>Model Open: {parameter1}</div>
            <div>{JSON.stringify(parameter2)}</div>
            </>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookingModalPopup

and call this CompA from another component for example
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <CompA/>
    </main>
  );
}

this will solve your issue.

You just use the ModelProps interface in your BookingModalPopup component, you can specify the type of the modelProps parameter in the function signature.
import React from "react";
interface ModelProps {
 modalOpen?: boolean;
 data: any;
 reloadParent: () => void;
closeModal: () => void;}


interface Props {
  modelProps: ModelProps;
}
    const BookingModalPopup: React.FC<Props> = ({ modelProps }) => {
  // Access the data property safely using optional chaining
  const data = modelProps?.data;
  // Use the data in your component
  return <div>Test</div>;
};

export default BookingModalPopup;


you mean to use ModelProps inside BookingModalPopup component instead of declaring outside?

Yes, that's correct! If you want to use ModelProps inside the BookingModalPopup component instead of declaring it outside, you can do so.
